# Max flow min cut for alternating flow

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-optimization

Is there a similar theorem to max flow min cut for finding max flow in a digraph where edges are colored red and blue, and the flow is required to alternate between red and blue edges? I may also allow the assumption that the source only has red out-edges and the sink only has blue in-edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that you can apply max flow min cut to the graph where you have two copies of each vertex from the original graph: the first one has only red out-edges and blue in-edges, while the second one has blue out-edges and red in-edges.